# Need help to understand foreach function in make files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Hello I am trying to understand the principle of the foreach function. As it is obvious that I am new in make system, so I need some more clarification on what is really happening. So in following example:

```
dirs := a b c d
files := $(foreach dir,$(dirs),$(wildcard $(dir)/*)
```

will expand to

```
files := $(wildcard a/* b/* c/* d/*)
```

So what **dir** is, and what is it for? Isn't it somehow redundant? My suggestion is that dir accepts the value of each consecutive(space separate) value of dirs for each iteration. Then wildcard function does its job.

Comment: Why not creating an experimental minimal makefile and study the real-life behavior?

Comment: You say here that the first example "will expand to" the second, but that's not true (and that's not what the GNU make manual says).  The manuals says that the first example _has the same result as_ the second, which is entirely different.  If you mean "will expand to the same value as", rather than "will expand to", then I'd agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreach has the following syntax: 
`foreach(var, list, text)`.

Basically, `var` takes the value for each element in `list`, and then `text` is executed. You use `var` (or `dir` in your example), to specify in `text` a command (or series of commands) to be performed on `dir`.

For other readers, OP's example is taken from the [GNU Make file manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function).